# How to return result correctly so that I can access it from the view?

Tags: c#, episerver

I am trying to build a custom report in the EpiServer Report Center to display a table of all users.

I have created a ViewModel and am trying to populate a variable called UserStore:

```
using EPiServer.Cms.UI.AspNetIdentity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebProject.Site.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class UsersReportViewModel
    {
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityDbContext("EPiServerDB"));

        return userStore;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access it from my view like so:

```
@model UsersReportViewModel


@{
    Layout = null;

}

<div class="users-table">@Model.userStore;</div>
```

I am currently getting two errors:

1. in the ViewModel, where it says return UserStore;

> The name userStore does not exist in the current context.

2. in the View:

> UsersReportViewModel.userStore is inaccessible due to its protection
> level

**Please ignore this question I have thought better of my approach. This question is no longer relevant.**

Comment: It's inaccessible because it's not public. It doesn't exist because that's not classes work. You can however return the value in the `getter` of the attribute but not like this

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not public so there is no way you can get it. Add `public` access modifier to the start to access it.

2)Access/ set the value such as

```
public UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore
{
    get{
        if(this.value == null){
            this.value = new UserStore<ApplicationUser> 
                                   (new IdentityDbContext("EPiServerDB"));

            return this.value;
        }
        else
            return this.value;
    }
}
```